# Summarizing point data to multi point data and creating convex hull in R

Tags: r, convex-hull

I have latitude and longitude information like 26.847905 73.9575005 for about 800 points, I need to trim these lat/lon information to say 3 decimal places.

I used the following syntax in R

```
# Rounding off Coordinates of each of point to 3 decimal places
shp1_DE$lon <- round(shp1_DE$coords.x1, 3)
shp1_DE$lat <- round(shp1_DE$coords.x2, 3)
```

Now I have many points with lat/lon for example 26.847, 73.957 etc...

I want to summarize data to these points and form point-multipoint shapefile.

After that I need to create convex hull for each of these features. How to go about it in R?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! It's unclear what you mean by 'summarise data' to a 'point-multipoint' geometry. What do your other data look like? What kind of 'summary'? Why are you reducing the decimal places of your coordinates - are you trying to create a grid and calculate average grid values?

Comment: @Simbamangu  I need to form clusters based on distance (to begin with). By reducing from **8 decimal places** to **3 decimal places** I am trying to group the points, which is not an ideal method. By _Summarization_ I mean grouping, since after the step of rounding off to 3 decimal places there are many points with same lat-lon, I now want one feature class (be it point if it has unique lat-lon or multi-points with same lat-lon) for each of newly formed Lat-lon. In Alteryx this is _Summarization_ in sql this _Group by_.

Answer (score 2):

To create a convex hull you can use function `chull` from `grDevices`.

NB: This function returns the *indices* of the points in the input, not the points itself. Furthermore I was using it to draw lines, so I had to add the first point again as last point. The code I used looks like this:

```
hull <- chull(topo)
hull <- c(hull, hpts[1])
hullpts <- topo[hull,c(1,2)]
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, I will try this, but first I need to summarize my data on unique lat/lon. Do you know how to create multi-point feature via summarization?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite unclear what you attempt to do. For instance *summarize* and *feature* are quite vague without further context. So I am guessing here.

With your rounding of the coordinates you in effect moved the points in "square" cells to a central point for each cell. You don't need to. Just imagine the cells, and loop over them, calculating the aggregate you need (count/sum/avg(?)) for the points in each cell.

Every grid-cell could then serve as the complex hull for the points inside it. Use `rect()` and `text()` to draw the results into a plot.